# Is the Good Question badge awarded for a "Question score of 25 or more" or for a "Question voted up more than 25 times"?

Tags: support, badges

I am looking for the criteria for the Good Question badge. I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) that it is awarded for a

> Question score of 25 or more

However, [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/07/12/stack-overflow-badge-feedbac/) I see:

> Question voted up more than 25 times

My understanding is that a question with 25 up & 25 downvotes is not eligible for the badge according to the first definition, but it is according to the second definition.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct information is on the badge page. The question has to a have a *score* of 25 or more. It is important to note that you don't lose the badge if the question score drops below 25 at some point in the future.

That blog post is 12 years old and should be considered outdated.